# Uri.TryCreate returns true for any string value?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, url, uri

I'm trying to validate a Uri using the Uri.TryCreate method and when I called it with an invalid string, the method returned true. Any ideas why? My code is below:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri tempValue;
        if (Uri.TryCreate("NotAURL", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out tempValue))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("?");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's a valid relative URL.  An example of a invalid URI is:

```
"http://example.com<>"
```

If you want to allow only absolute URIs, use `UriKind.Absolute`.

The example will then fail to parse.

Comment: Interesting, I guess I didn't think of it as a folder. I'm trying to validate website URLs, so I wasn't thinking about folder paths. Thanks!

Comment: It could be a relative URI on a website.  E.g. if you're on `http://example.com/`, that relative URL refers to `http://example.com/NotAURL`.

Comment: Yea, that's what I did -- switched it to UriKind.Absolute. Thanks again.

Comment: Empty string or "?" are also valid relative uris according to this method. How does that make sense?

Comment: Using empty string as a relative URL refers to the current document. For example, if the current document is `http://example.org/foo/bar.html`, then an empty relative URL refers to the same file. Relative URL `?` also refers to the same file with an empty query string; if the original URL already has a query string, the new one replaces the old. For example, starting from `http://example.org/foo/bar.html?foo=bar`, the relative URL `?baz=qux` yields `http://example.org/foo/bar.html?baz=qux`. (An empty relative URL preserves the original query string.)