# Why Uri.TryCreate throws NRE when url contains Turkish character?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-core, .net-4.6.1

I have encountered an interesting situation where I get `NRE` from `Uri.TryCreate` method when it's supposed to return `false`.

You can reproduce the issue like below:

```
Uri url;
if (Uri.TryCreate("http:Ç", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out url))
{
    Console.WriteLine("success");
}
```

I guess it's failing during the parse, but when I try `"http:A"` for example, it returns `true` and parses it as relative url. Even if fails on parse it should just return `false` as I understand, what could be the problem here? This seems like a bug in the implementation cause documentation doesn't mention about any exception on this method.

The error occurs in .NET 4.6.1 but not 4.0

Comment: Your example works for me  in LinqPad. Maybe use UriKind.Absolute?  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161247/uri-trycreate-returns-true-for-any-string-value

Comment: @Greg in my case though it throws a NullReferenceException in Uri.CreateUriInfo. Which .NET version did you use for the test?

Comment: @Greg forget to mention .net version, might be related

Comment: Works in LP4, Fails in LP5

Comment: @AlexK. which means this is a 4.6 bug

Comment: The .NET version is actually the *MOST* important information in this question. Please *don't* remove it, this is vandalism

Comment: I can reproduce for 4.5+. Since 4.0 is no longer supported, this means the bug affect all modern versions.

Comment: Throws an exception for any non ascii character it seems, e.g. ö or 日

Comment: Breaking change in 4.5.2
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004214/system-uri-tostring-behaviour-change-after-vs2012-install and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx#core

Comment: @Greg these changes aren't supposed to throw an unrelated exception though. `TryCreate` should return `false` in this case. This *is* a bug

Comment: NRE always is a bug by convention under any circumstances.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778454/breaking-change-to-uri-iswellformeduristring-in-net-4-5

Comment: I opened a bug ticket as well: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2826777

Comment: @SelmanGenç when you post Connect issues they should be as detailed as possible. You have to make it so that whoever triages the issue *can't* dismiss it out of hand. Even well written issues get ignored all the time. The canned response sounds too much like a dismissal

Comment: Repro on .Net core too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos okey, this is my first time :) I will try to be more detailed in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in the .NET framework. You can open a ticket on MicrosoftConnect.

The exception will be raised in this method

```
void Systen.Uri.CreateUriInfo(System.Uri.Flags cF)
```

on line 2290 (inspect the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/URI.cs,2290)) executing following statement:

```
// This is NOT an ImplicitFile uri
idx = (ushort)m_Syntax.SchemeName.Length;
```

At this time, the `m_Syntax` object will be `null`, because during parsing, it will be discarded.

Method

```
void InitializeUri(ParsingError err, UriKind uriKind, out UriFormatException e)
```

[line 121](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/UriExt.cs,121):

```
if (m_Syntax.IsSimple)
{
    if ((err = PrivateParseMinimal()) != ParsingError.None)
    {
        if (uriKind != UriKind.Absolute && err <= ParsingError.LastRelativeUriOkErrIndex)
        {
            // RFC 3986 Section 5.4.2 - http:(relativeUri) may be considered a valid relative Uri.
            m_Syntax = null; // convert to relative uri
            e = null;
            m_Flags &= Flags.UserEscaped; // the only flag that makes sense for a relative uri
         }
         // ...
     }
    // ...
 }
```

The `PrivateParseMinimal()` method returns `ParsingError.BadAuthority` and `uriKind == UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` by your specification.

The `PrivateParseMinimal()` method looks for any of the following character sequences: "//", "\", "/\", "/". And since there are no such sequences in your input string, a `ParsingError.BadAuthority` code will be returned.